# Is it possible to reload specific browser tabs using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario like ,one main Tab which contains some master data . Once i click on a particular entry in master tab another tab(child tab) will open in same browser with more details of the selected entry. 
I can perform some update action in the child tab , and it will update the details in DB.

What i need to achieve is ,if i perform any action in child tab i need to refresh my Main tab so that whatever changes i have made in child page has to be reflected in main tab.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems too broad to me.

Comment: Question seems perfectly valid to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. In the child tab, use `opener` to call global functions in the master tab. The `opener` automatic global is a reference to the window that opened the current window. Note that if the user bookmarks the tab, closes it, and then opens it from the bookmark, `opener` won't be set anymore, since the window wasn't opened by another window.
2. Use [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) and have the master tab watch for the `storage` event on the window. When the child tab does (say) `localStorage.setItem("foo", "new value")`, the master tab will see the `storage` event and be able to see that the `"foo"` key's value changed. This has the advantage that you're not relying on the `opener` link; it doesn't matter how the child windows are opened, all windows within the same origin will see the `storage` event (if you use `localStorage` rather than `sessionStorage` — the event is also raised for `sessionStorage`, but only for windows that are sharing the same `sessionStorage` area; I have to admit I'm not au fait with the details of how that happens but it doesn't happen with the simple "this window opened another", it has to to with not being a "top level browsing context," so for your use case, `localStorage` is probably the one you want).

#### Example of #1

In `master.html`, we have a link that opens a tab:

```
<a href="child.html" target="_blank">Click to open child tab</a>
```

...and a global function (note that it's important that it be global):

```
function tabUpdate(update) {
    // Do something with the update from the child tab
    $("<p>").html(update).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

In `child.html`, we do this when we need to do an update:

```
opener.tabUpdate("Update at " + Date.now());
```

#### Example of #2

In `master.html`:

```
$(window).on("storage", function(e) {
    var event = e.originalEvent; // Get access to the storage-specifics
    if (event.key == "foo") { // Or whatever
        // Do something with event.newValue
    }
});
```

In `child.html`:

```
// When we want to send an update to master:
localStorage.setItem("foo", "new value");
```

Comment: `opener` would it work for new tab window? although i have not used it.

Comment: @Jai: Yes, it doesn't matter whether it's a pop-up or tab. What matters is whether another window opened it (via `target="..."` on a link, or via `window.open`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @crowder. So if i open multiple child tabs from main tab , i can find the reference to the main tab that opens child tab and reload it whenever there is any action performed in child tab. About the second option "Web storage" seems to be little bit broad to me.

Comment: @Cyber: What do you mean by "broad"?