# Refresh a page with JavaScript and its window.name (same as html attribute "target")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A user opens a page `dashboard.html` (by typing in browser url bar) and the pages names itself with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.name = "dashboard";
</script>
```

The dashboard page contains 3 dynamic generated links:

```
<a href="dashboard.html" target="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
<a href="green.html" target="gr">Green</a>
<a href="blue.html" target="bl">Blue</a>
<a href="red.html" target="re">Red</a>
```

Every of the tabs contains the same links as above. All target names are random, unique and fixed. So the user has 4 tabs (Dashboard + 3 tabs). Every link shows the page in its fixed browser tab no matter where the user clicks.

The Problem: is it possible to reload the dashboard-tab from one of the pages with Javascript?

**Important: the tabs are not childs from `dashboard.html`**

After a user opens the `dashboard.html` he clicks on `green.html`. Then the user is on page `green.html` and clicks on `blue.html`. So `blue.html` is not a child from `dashboard.html`.

After changes on red.html the `dashboard.html` should be reloaded.

This question is similar but works with parent and child tabs. I do not fully understand this solution related to my problem :(
[Is it possible to reload specific browser tabs using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647972/is-it-possible-to-reload-specific-browser-tabs-using-javascript)

I didn't make it work. I'm afraid it's not even possible. 
Any hint or help appreciated. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: If you didn't open the page, I dont think there's a way to reload them unless you let them all connect to a unified service that then pings everyone connected to reload themselves (or just specific pages). That requires an intermediary though, so thats a lot more work.

Comment: yes, my script didnt open the dashboard-page, the user did. A ping or ajax-request would cause a too high load in my use-case. 
In JavaScript is no way to access a html-page similar as the html attribut target does with <a href="#" target="dashboard">. Too bad.

Comment: For security reasons you cannot. Imagine any page controller any tab and the havoc that would ensue. Not pretty.

Comment: yeah, makes sense!